# Joining two tables in a MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called votes:

[image: Votes]

I'm trying to join a list of items, with a users table, and this votes table.

```
      SELECT list_items.item_id, text, date_added, username 
        FROM list_items 
NATURAL JOIN users, votes 
       WHERE list_id = 3
```

That query is giving me this:

[image: SQL Query Preformed]

I would like to get a total vote count for each list_item, as well a column for `up_votes` and another for `down_votes`. And, of course, I don't want the item_id's to repeat like that.

I tried combining SUM with IF as explained in a [Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/quick-tip-working-with-mysql-and-sum/) video, but the tutorial was too simple.

**EDIT:** Here's the list_items table:
[image: list_items]

Comment: Can we see just the skeleton of the list_items table if possible?

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is the worst syntax -- we can't see what's being joined on, and the query will return different results if the column names change.

Comment: I've just updated the post to include the list_items table.

Comment: Blimey, a `NATURAL JOIN`. That takes me back!

Comment: Personally, I prefer UNNATURAL JOINs (you know, IRRATIONAL JOIN / ZOMBIE JOIN / MANBEARPIG JOIN). Kidding aside, NATURAL JOINs are considered to be pretty dangerous; you should switch to a more explicit syntax.

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks! I was following the examples here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT list_items.text, list_items.item_id, SUM(votes.vote=1) AS upvote, SUM(votes.vote=-1) AS downvote
FROM list_items
LEFT JOIN votes ON list_items.item_id = votes.item_id
```

The tricky part are the two sum calls - If the vote field is `1`, then `vote=1` which evaluates to TRUE, which MySQL will cast to an integer 1 for the purposes of the SUM(). If it's not 1, then it evaluates to false which is cast to a 0 and doesn't do anything for the SUM().

---

whoops, needs to have

```
GROUP BY list_items.item.id
```

at the end.

Comment: The problem with this is that it only returns one row and the upvote and downvote counts for the item are wrong as well. http://imgur.com/9b4AM

Comment: whoops. should've had a group by in there as well. I'll edit up the answer.

Comment: ALMOST there! I made a couple of changes to get the user_id and the date_added from the list_items table, but I also wanted it to get the username from the users table (as in the third screenshot). This is what it looks like now: http://i.imgur.com/8jx4v.png and here is the query: http://pastebin.com/YVGkk9AW

Comment: Presumably you'd need to group on the user_id field as well, otherwise you'll get some random single ID, even  though multiple users may have voted. If you want all of the user IDs in that one field, then use group_concat() (though that has a 1024 char limit on what it returns).

Comment: This is what I get when I join the users table: http://i.imgur.com/hqGEg.png Unfortunately, it's causing the vote counts to be off. When I then group it by username as well, it just gives me four rows. :[

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    SELECT li.item_id, li.text, li.date_added, u.username,
           SUM(IF(v.vote = 1, 1, 0)) up_votes,
           SUM(IF(v.vote = -1, 1, 0)) down_votes,
           COUNT(v.vote) total_votes
      FROM list_items li
INNER JOIN users u ON li.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN votes v ON li.item_id = v.item_id
     WHERE li.list_id = 3
  GROUP BY li.item_id
```

Assumed the column of the user id is named `id` on your users table.

Comment: That is very close to what I want! The one thing is seems to be ignoring one of the list items. This is what it looked like: http://imgur.com/Wc7W6

Comment: @Daniel O'Connor: Changed my query, try with the new one. Changed the last join from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, check and let me know if it returns both items.

Comment: @Daniel O'Connor: I am too tired (way too low on battery) to debug now, will give you an answer tomorrow morning. :)

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate all the help! All this advanced SQL querys are jibberish to me, but I hope to learn soon.

Comment: @Daniel O'Connor: Updated my answer, try that.